# Oracle APEX Close Modal Page with Javascript After 3 Seconds

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-5

I use in Dynamic Action Javascript to close my current modal page like this:

```
apex.navigation.dialog.close(true)
```

Is it possible to close my current modal page after 3 seconds? Because i want first to show a notification  like this :
show_notification('Please Do Something');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it!!

```
setTimeout(function() {apex.navigation.dialog.close(true)}, 3000);
```